# How to seal around an existing wood window after removing old siding

Tags: windows, sealing, siding, caulking

We are removing old siding from a house, and replacing it with Hardie lap siding.  We are leaving the original wood-framed picture window in place.  With the siding removed there are gaps between the window jamb and the sheathing.  Should we use caulk or peel-and-stick, or both, as an extra precaution against potential water damage, before we apply the house wrap?

Comment: Maybe non-expanding foam.   Do NOT use epxanding foam, it could warp the frames.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be sanding them and caulking them before applying the house wrap.

Comment: The gaps are between the jamb and the sheathing ~ does this need to be wrapped with peel-and-stick in addition to the caulk, because some of the gaps are approximately 1/3 inch wide?